# How do I ensure my Profile Image is uploaded during registration?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am trying to implement a simple Custom-User-Registration using `django-rest-framework`, django-allauth and dj-rest-auth.

When I update my user details and add an Image the Image gets uploaded to the correct folder, but when I select the image during registration, the image is not uploaded. What am I doing wrong?

This is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

GENDER_SELECTION = [
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
]


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # email attribute is inherited from AbstractUser
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_SELECTION)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/', blank=True)
```

This is my `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'phone_number', 'gender', 'image',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'phone_number', 'gender', 'image',)
```

This is my `serializers.py`

```
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework import serializers
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer as RestAuthLoginSerializer

from users.models import GENDER_SELECTION
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_SELECTION)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_null=True, required=False)

    # Define transaction.atomic to rollback the save operation in case of error
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.gender = self.data.get('gender')
        user.phone_number = self.data.get('phone_number')
        user.image = self.data.get('image')
        user.save()
        return user


class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'gender', 'image',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'email',)
```

My `settings.py` file for reference

```
...

# Custom Settings

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
}

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.LoginSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer',
}

REST_USE_JWT = True
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'my-app-auth'

LOGIN_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

My Image gets uploaded when I update my User, but it does not upload when I select the file during registration process.

Comment: Have you got a solution to this problem? I'm encountering the same problem.